# Using app bundle over splitting app in android

Tags: android, cpu-architecture, android-app-bundle

My app is using native library , in order to reduce apk size I used apk splitting as following

```
    splits {
        abi{
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86_64','x86','armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

Now my question is , if I generate app bundle instead of apk , do I need to keep the above snippet in my gradle file ? Or app bundle will automatically reduce the app size based on cpu architecture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of this entire snippet, App Bundle is configured by default to generate APKs split by three dimensions: ABI, DPI and language.